# Computing cross product using norm and angle

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, cross-product

Sorry for the weird title, if someone finds a better title for my problem be my guest to edit it ;)

---

> For $\mathbf{v,w} $ in R³ with $\mathbf{||v||=1 ;||w||=4; \theta
>  =\frac{2\pi}{3}}$
>
> Solve the following:
>
> 1. $\lVert (3v+w)\times(v-2w)\rVert$
> 2. $\langle w\times 5v, v-3w\rangle$

I've already calculated

$$\langle v,w\rangle = \frac{-1}{2}||v|| \cdot||w|| =-2$$

Also, I've transformed 1. into

$$\lVert-7(v\times w)\rVert$$

But I'm a bit lost here.

Next I masked $w\times 5v $ as $x$ so as 2. we now have

$$\langle x,v-3w\rangle$$

This all seems to bring me not a bit closer to the solution, can someone suggest a valid approach?

Comment: I don't think you can solve this without knowing what $\theta$ is (you present an inequality).

Comment: sry, blockquote smuggled a > in there. Corrected it

Comment: *Sigh*. I suspected that the misuse of "solve" had crept its way into textbooks, and it seems I was right. One solves equations, but one computes/evaluates expressions such as integrals or the ones from your book.

Comment: I just didn't know the difference, my choice of words wasn't based on any literature

Answer (score 2):

Just as $v \cdot w = |w| |v| \cos \theta$, there is a corresponding formula $|v \times w| = |v| |w| \sin \theta$.  Since the angle and the lengths are known, you should be able to compute this magnitude.

Comment: would you mind adding an approach for 2. ?

Comment: You already found that (2) reduces to $|-7(v \times w)|$.  You know $|v \times w|$ from the formula I have given.  You then multiply by 7.

Comment: made a mistake in my original question, 1. transforms into $||-7(v\times w)||$

Comment: The vector $v \times w$ is orthogonal to both $v, w$.  You should be able to see that $w \times 5v = 5(w \times v) = -5 (v \times w)$.  You should then be able to distribute the inner product, so that you form only inner products of $v \times w$ with $v$ or $w$, multiplied by scalars.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** First,
$$
\begin{align}
(3v+w)\times(v-2w)
&=-7v\times w
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\|-7v\times w\|=7\|v\|\|w\|\left|\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)\right|
$$
For $\langle w\times 5v, v-3w\rangle$, note that $w\times v$ is perpendicular to both $v$ and $w$.